# AngularJS - Controlling ngRepeat data from Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a JS object $scope.appoinments, with 3 objects inside (completed, rejected and pending). The fact is the data is provided by my server, but the view is rendered before we get the data (even if I call the function on init of the controller).

When I get the data, the Ç$scope don't applies that data to the ngRepeat over the view. And if I use `$scope.$apply()` I get an error saying `The digest is in process`.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item item-divider">
      Pending Appointments
    </li>
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="pending in appointments.pending">
      {{pending.service_id}}
    </li>
    <li class="item item-divider">
      Completed Appointments
    </li>
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="completed in appointments.completados">
      {{completed.service_id}}
    </li>
    <li class="item item-divider">
      Rejected Appointments
    </li>
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="rejected in appointments.rechazados">
      {{rejected.service_id}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Controller:

```
closer.controller('appointmentsController', function($scope, Session, CLOSER_SERVER, $http) {
    $scope.session_id = Session.getId();
    $scope.appointments = {
      pending: {},
      completed: {},
      rejected: {}
    };

    $scope.load_appoint = function (){
      var urlMaker = CLOSER_SERVER.url;
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: urlMaker
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.appointments = response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
             //
        });
    }
    $scope.load_appoint();
});

Response of the server:

    {"pending":[],"completed":[{"service_id":"25","date":"10/01/2016","time":"12:00:00","place":"Undefined","comments":"No comments"}],"rejected":[]}
```

How can I modify the data of the ngRepeats within the controller??

Comment: `$scope.appointments = response.data;`

Comment: you can get your answer by just console logging your response

Comment: I am logging the response, but the response seems to be OK, I edit the post to show you the response.

Comment: normally, the response from a callback has a data component, so instead of storing the response AS the appointments, it is most likely response.data.

Comment: Not in this case, I configured the server, the response is an array encoded to json, exact as the used by the AngularJS app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your definiton of `$scope.appointments`:

```
$scope.appointments = {
  pending: {},
  completed: {},
  rejected: {}
};
```

Notice how `response.pending`, `response.completed`, and `respose.rejected`,  are coming back from the server as *arrays* ([]), not Object ({}).

I'm making the assumption that the problem exists within your *callback* (.then). Take a look at the response your server sends by using `console.log` and see if you can't match the data response to what Angular is expecting.

Comment: That was completely the issue. I do in PHP `$output = array(array(),array(),array())` then `json_encode` the output for return. How would I have to do?

Answer (score 3):

From the Docs:

> ### $http General usage
>
> ```
> $http({
>   method: 'GET',
>   url: '/someUrl'
> }).then(function successCallback(response) {
>     // this callback will be called asynchronously
>     // when the response is available
>   }, function errorCallback(response) {
>     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
>     // or server returns response with an error status.
>   });
> ```
>
> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
>     -statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

-- [AngularJS $http service API Reference -- general usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

Both [@nikhil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1132354/nikhil) and [@Fallenrepear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1404049/fallenreaper) are right.

You really should use:

```
$scope.appointments = response.data;
```

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge. I have tried it. The console shows status 200, the data and the headers, all printed out.  But the ngRepeat still don't refresh.

Comment: For debugging purposes, put some bindings outside the `ng-repeat` to see the data `{{appointments}}`, `{{appointments.pending}}`. See what renders. Then further debugging, inside the `ng-repeat` put `{{pending}}`. Also inside and outside the `ng-repeat` put `{{$id}}` to see the scope numbers. See what you get.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of .then , use .success in your http request and then console log your response.

Comment: `success` is deprecated. Please do not suggest using it.